# How not to display duplicates on ruby on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an app that lets user upload videos from youtube, but users upload from the same artist multiple times but different songs. I need it to show only one song from the artist. right now this are the results im getting. "Sensato" is being put in 2 diffent groups even though is the same name of the artist.

**Group**
El mayor - debarata

**Group**
El Alfa - jevi

**Group** 
Future - where ya at

**Group**
Sensato - Se Feliz

**Group**
Sensato - Bello

(Controller)

```
def index
    @items = Video.all.order("cached_votes_up DESC, artist ASC")
    @items_by_day = @items.group_by { |t| t.artist }

end
```

(view)

```
    <% @items_by_day.each do |day, items| %>

            <div class="row">
            <h1>Group</h1>

            <% for a in items %>
            <div class="videothumb col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <div class="" style="
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 240px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;">

                    <%= link_to  a do %>
  <div style="background: rgba(0,0,0, 0); width:100%; height: 85%;z-index:1000; position:absolute; top:0;"></div> 
<% end %>
                    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= a.url %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                    </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h3>
                    <%= link_to a.title, a %> </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h2><%= a.artist %></h2>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">

                    <div style="text-align:right">
                        <%= link_to like_video_path(a), method: :put, class: "" do %>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up">
                                <%= a.get_upvotes.size %>
                        <% end %> 
                        <%= link_to dislike_video_path(a), method: :put, class: "" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
        <%= a.get_downvotes.size %>
      <% end %>

                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
            <% end %>

            </div>


<% end %>
```

(model)

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable
    belongs_to :user

    validates :title,
        presence: true,
        length: { minimum: 3 },
        uniqueness: true

    validates :url,
        presence: true,
        length: { minimum: 3 },
        uniqueness: true

    validates :genre, presence: true
end
```

(migration)

```
class CreateVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :videos do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :artist
      t.string :url
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Final Result should look like this

**Group**
El mayor - debarata

**Group**
El Alfa - jevi

**Group** 
Future - where ya at

**Group**
Sensato - Se Feliz

Comment: Let's see your video model and how it is related to Artist.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
@items_by_day = @items.select('artist').uniq.group('artist')
```

#### Update

Try this:

```
def index
  @items = Video.all.order("cached_votes_up DESC, artist ASC")
  @items_by_day = Video.select('artist').uniq.group('artist').joins('videos')
end
```

Comment: This gave me this error

PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list LINE 1: ...ISTINCT "videos"."artist" FROM "videos" ORDER BY cached_vot... ^ : SELECT DISTINCT "videos"."artist" FROM "videos" ORDER BY cached_votes_up DESC, artist ASC

Comment: please post the `Video` model.

Comment: `class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable
    belongs_to :user
    
    validates :title,
        presence: true,
        length: { minimum: 3 },
        uniqueness: true
    
    validates :url,
        presence: true,
        length: { minimum: 3 },
        uniqueness: true
        
    validates :genre, presence: true
end`

Comment: I dont have a model for the artist. I'm running everything through video model. so when comes to the site this the flow -> signs up -> post video -> then with the info they submitted I'm breaking it up in the views. I didnt want to do a artist model because users wont be creating artist accounts they just putting their favorite artist songs.

Comment: `artist` is not an attribute of the Video model?

Comment: its telling me the an error with this line
 <% @items_by_day.each do |day, items| %>

PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ROM "videos" GROUP BY "videos"."artist"  ORDER BY cached_vot...
                                                             ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "videos"."artist" FROM "videos" GROUP BY "videos"."artist"  ORDER BY cached_votes_up DESC, artist ASC

Comment: it assumes that artist is a column in the videos table. how do you get an artist for a particular video?

Comment: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #35):
33
34
35
36
37
38
              
            
            
            <% for a in items %>

Comment: so if i want to display the artist i go into the videos table. Videos(:id).artist

Comment: please paste the content of the `videos` table

Comment: https://github.com/jaysg/tuchoice heres the github just put it up see the full picture

Comment: https://tuchoice.herokuapp.com/artists heres a preview of the app on heroku so u can see its showing 2 videos on el alfa i just want one video per artist

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for this (using the [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods `group` method](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group)):

```
def index
    @items = Video.all.order(cached_votes_up: :desc, artist: :asc)
    @items_by_day = Video.select(:title, 'MAX(cached_votes_up) as cached_votes_up', 'MIN(id) as id').group(:artist)
end
```

(Also, notice that I'm using a ruby hash for the `order` params rather than a string, this is really the preferred method when possible.)

Comment: I got this error

Showing /Users/antracks/code/personal/ror/tuchoice/app/views/artists/index.html.erb where line #27 raised:

PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "videos.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" GROUP BY "videos"."artist"  ...
               ^
: SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" GROUP BY "videos"."artist"  ORDER BY "videos"."cached_votes_up" DESC, "videos"."artist" ASC
Extracted source (around line #27):
<% @items_by_day.each do |day, items| %><div class="row">
            <h1>Group</h1>

Comment: It looks like you only want on title, so maybe just grab the first one (using `minimum(:id)`) then grab its `maximum(:cached_votes_up)`. I've edited my code above.

Comment: undefined method `maximum' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: Ok, I should have use the SQL functions instead of the ActiveRecord functions. I've updated my code again.

Comment: with the latest code is giving me this error <% @items_by_day.each do |day, items| %> maybe you can help me create a new view. I think what your giving me is right but i need to change the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87667/discussion-between-karl-wilbur-and-joe-santos-garcia).